# How to parallelize the numpy operations in cython

Tags: python, performance, numpy, parallel-processing, cython

I am trying to parallelize the following code which includes numerous numpy array operations

```
    #fft_fit.pyx
    import cython
    import numpy as np
    cimport numpy as np
    from cython.parallel cimport prange
    from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

    dat1 = np.genfromtxt('/home/bagchilab/Sumanta_files/fourier_ecology_sample_data_set.csv',delimiter=',')
    dat = np.delete(dat1, 0, 0)
    yr = np.unique(dat[:,0])
    fit_dat = np.empty([1,2])


    def fft_fit_yr(np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] yr, np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] dat, int yr_idx, int pix_idx):
        cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] yr_dat1 
        cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] yr_dat
        cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] fft_dat
        cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] fft_imp_dat
        cdef int len_yr = len(yr)
        for i in prange(len_yr ,nogil=True):
            with gil:

                yr_dat1 = dat[dat[:,yr_idx]==yr[i]]
                yr_dat = yr_dat1[~np.isnan(yr_dat1).any(axis=1)]
                print "index" ,i
                y_fft = np.fft.fft(yr_dat[:,pix_idx])
                y_fft_abs = np.abs(y_fft)
                y_fft_freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(y_fft), 1)
                x_fft = range(len(y_fft))
                fft_dat = np.column_stack((y_fft, y_fft_abs))
                cut_off_freq = np.percentile(y_fft_abs, 25)
                imp_freq =  np.array(y_fft_abs[y_fft_abs > cut_off_freq])
                fft_imp_dat = np.empty((1,2))
        for j in range(len(imp_freq)):
                    freq_dat = fft_dat[fft_dat[:, 1]==imp_freq[j]]
                    fft_imp_dat  = np.vstack((fft_imp_dat , freq_dat[0,:]))       
                fft_imp_dat = np.delete(fft_imp_dat, 0, 0)
                fit_dat1 = np.fft.ifft(fft_imp_dat[:,0])
                fit_dat2 = np.column_stack((fit_dat1.real, [yr[i]] * len(fit_dat1)))
                fit_dat = np.concatenate((fit_dat, fit_dat2), axis = 0)
```

I have used the following code for setup.py

```
    ####setup.py
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

    setup(
cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
ext_modules = [Extension("fft_fit_yr", ["fft_fit.pyx"])]
    extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp'],
    extra_link_args=['-fopenmp'])]
    )
```

But I am getting the following error when I compile the fft_fit.pyx in cython:

```
    for i in prange(len_yr ,nogil=True):
    target may not be a Python object as we don't have the GIL
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong while using prange function.
Thanks.

Comment: Three points: 1) the specific error message you get it probably because you haven't `cdef`ed `i` to be an integer. 2) it's fine to use `with gil:` in `prange` for small chunks, but those parts can't be executed in parallel so it's utterly pointless to have the _whole_ thing in `with gil:`. 3) ali_m is right - the stuff you're doing won't work in a `prange` section. The mutliprocessing is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! It would be of great help if you please let me know how to use multiprocessing in this code.

Answer (score 4):

You can't (at least not using Cython).

Numpy functions operate on Python objects and therefore require the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock), which prevents multiple native threads from executing in parallel. If you compile your code using [`cython -a`](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html#determining-where-to-add-types), you will get an annotated HTML file which shows where Python C-API calls are being made (and therefore where the GIL can't be released).

Cython is most useful where you have a specific bottleneck in your code that cannot be easily speeded up using vectorization. If your code is already spending most of its time in numpy function calls then calling those exact same functions from Cython is not going to result in any significant performance improvement. In order to see a noticeable difference you would need to write some or all of your array operations as explicit `for` loops. However it looks to me as though there are much simpler optimizations that could be made to your code.

I suggest that you do the following:

1. Profile your original Python code (e.g. using [`line_profiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler)) to see where the bottlenecks are.
2. Focus your attention on speeding up these bottlenecks in the *single-threaded* version. You should ask a separate question on SO if you want help with this.
3. If the optimized single-threaded version is still too slow for your needs, parallelize it using [`joblib`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/) or [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). Parallelization is usually the *last* tool to reach for once you've already tried everything else you can think of.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and explaining the default in my code. I will try to optimize this code on single thread. But it would be of great help if you could direct me to any similar codes or hints, where parallelization is carried on multiple numpy array operations.

Comment: It's much more helpful for future readers if you keep your questions focused - it would be better to ask a separate question if you want help with optimizing your single-threaded version. As I mentioned above, `joblib` is one of the easiest methods to parallelize your numpy function calls. It is basically a convenience wrapper around the `multiprocessing` Python builtin module. You should look at the documentation I linked to in my answer for some examples showing how to use it.